# How to store login state of Facebook in Android with SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have not push "Log out" ,how to keep "Log in" state ?

anyway,I restart program etc.
    (I use Facebook sdk  3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

1. You can get the accesstoken from the first valid session.

   ```
   String token  =  session.getAccessToken()
   ```

   Then save this in sharepreferences.
2. Then before you procceed with other functions, read the stored session is check weather the session is not null and is open.

   ```
   if(session.isOpened())
   {
    //proceed
   }
   ```