# How to store user logged in state in facebook sdk 4.4.0 android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How do i store user logged in state in android facebook SDK. According to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462461/how-to-store-login-state-of-facebook-in-android-with-sdk-3-0). It is suggested to use session. But in new facebook SDK session has been removed as give [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x). So how do i proceed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Facebook SDK 4.x now automatically stores the user logged in state.

Instead of using `session`, you should check `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` at `onCreate()`, and if not null, skip login.

Also from the official docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x), `AccessToken` broadcasts events when it is set, unset or updated. The `currentAccessToken` is automatically cached.